# Finding points of self intersection

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametric, plane-curves

A curve is parameterised by $$\mathbf{r}(t)=((2+\cos 3t)\cos 2t, (2+\cos 3t)(\sin 2t)), t\in [0,2\pi ]. $$
How can I find the self intersection points? I set $\mathbf{r}(t_1)=\mathbf{r}(t_2)$ and then tried to solve the simultaneous equations but it doesn't seem to work out. Any pointers?

Comment: To find points of self intersection of a curve algebraically isn't all that easy. Many times, a particular value for $t$ that dictates self intersection cannot be explicitly found. Hint: graphing and maybe by inspection you can find 2 different  $t$ values that describe the same point...

Comment: I think I'm being asked to explicitly calculate the points of self intersection in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: HINT There should be two slopes for same radius at intersection point.

Comment: Use that $x=(2+(4(\cos{t})^3-3(\cos{t})))(2(\cos{t})^2-1)$ $y=(2+(4(\cos{t})^3-3(\cos{t})))(2(\cos{t})(\sin{t}))$ and `R=QQ[c,s,x,y,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]`
`I=ideal(x-(2+(4*c^3-3*c))*(2*c^2-1),y-(2+(4*c^3-3*c))*(2*c*s),c^2+s^2-1)`
`gens gb I` in [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/).

Comment: Then to find the singular points of  your curve $$f=4\,x^{10}+20\,x^{8}y^{2}+40\,x^{6}y^{4}+40\,x^{4}y^{6}+20\,x^{2}y^{8}+4
      \,y^{10}-36\,x^{8}-144\,x^{6}y^{2}-216\,x^{4}y^{4}-144\,x^{2}y^{6}-36\,y
      ^{8}-16\,x^{7}+16\,x^{5}y^{2}+80\,x^{3}y^{4}+48\,x\,y^{6}+48\,x^{6}+153\,
      x^{4}y^{2}+138\,x^{2}y^{4}+49\,y^{6}=0$$ you can issue the command `primaryDecomposition ideal(f,diff(x,f),diff(y,f))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Geometrically**

Mathematica shows

[image]

Three point are
$$(1,1.7),(-2,0),(1,-1.7)$$

**Analytically**

(deleted)

Comment: I did that and I got exactly what you got but when I then substituted back in for the different values of k my answers didn't make sense.

Comment: I think what Narasimham said is the key of problem.

Comment: I understand the concept but I don't see how to use it to find the points.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric representation

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=((2+\cos 3t)\cos 2t, (2+\cos 3t)\sin 2t)), t\in [0,2\pi ]$$

can be replaced by this (complex) one

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=(2+\cos 3t)e^{2it} , t\in [0,2\pi ]$$

Thus, we are looking for values of $t_1$ and $t_2$, $t_1 \neq t_2$, such that:

$$\tag{1}(2+\cos 3t_1)e^{2it_1}=(2+\cos 3t_2)e^{2it_2}$$

Two complex numbers are equal if and only if their modules are equal and their arguments are equal (modulo $2 \pi$).

Remark:
Due to the fact that $2+\cos 3t>0$ for any value of $t$ shows that $2+\cos 3t_1$  and $2+\cos 3t_2$ are the modules of the LHS and RHS of (1), resp.

Thus, (1) is equivalent to:

$$\cases{\cos(3t_1)=\cos(3 t_2)\\2t_1=2t_2 \ modulo \ 2 \pi}$$

As $$cos(u)=cos(v) \ \iff \ u=\pm v+K 2\pi:$$

the previous conditions are equivalent to

$$\cases{3t_1= s 3 t_2+K 2\pi\\2t_1=2t_2+K' 2 \pi}$$

where $s=\pm1$ and $K,K'$ are integers.

$$\tag{2}\iff \ \ \cases{t_1= s t_2+K 2\pi/3\\t_1=t_2+K' \pi}$$

The cases where $s=1$ will not give double points (because they lead to $t_1=t_2+K''2\pi$). We can thus assume $s=-1$, i.e.,

$$\tag{3}\iff \ \ \cases{t_1= -t_2+K 2\pi/3 \ \ (a)\\t_1=t_2+K' \pi \ \ (b)}$$

Adding and substracting (3)(a) and (3)(b):

$$\tag{4}\cases{2t_1=K2\pi/3+K'\pi \ \ \iff \ \ t_1=K\pi/3+K'\pi/2\ \ (a)\\2t_2=K2\pi/3-K'\pi \ \ \iff \ \ t_2=K\pi/3-K'\pi/2 \ \ (b)}$$

**with the same values of $K$ and $K'$ in (4)(a) and (4)(b).**

For example, if $K=2$ and $K'=1$, $(t_1,t_2)=(7\pi/6,\pi/6)$, giving point $(1,\sqrt{3}).$

I leave you the task to consider the different other cases (by taking different possible cases for integers $K$ and $K'$, some of them being redundant). You will end up with the three following solutions (up to an exchange between $t_1$ and $t_2$, of course):

$$(t_1,t_2)=(7\pi/6,\pi/6), \ \ (5\pi/6,11\pi/6), \ \   \ \ (\pi/2,3\pi/2), $$ yielding double points :

$$(1,\sqrt{3}),  \ \ (1,-\sqrt{3}), \ \ (-2,0)$$

respectively.

Comment: I have slightly modified my answer. Is it convenient for you?

Comment: Absolutely. How did you think you switch it up to complex methods?

Comment: By recognizing a form (r(t)cos(at),r(t) sin(at)) which is expressed as a polar equation. As I didn't know if you had some practise of polar equations, I prefered to speak in terms of a complex valued function.